# Get variable MIN Date based on marker in row

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I'm using `MySQL` with `phpMyAdmin`,
below is my data table:

```
+--------+---------+-----------------+
| userID | context |      time       |
+--------+---------+-----------------+
|    111 |         | 7/1/2021        |
|    111 |         | 7/16/2019       |
|    111 | Reset   | 7/15/2019       |
|    222 |         | 7/9/2020        |
|    222 | Reset   | 7/8/2020        |
|    333 | Reset   | 5/11/2020       |
|    333 |         | 5/10/2020       |
|    444 |         | 9/8/2020        |
+--------+---------+-----------------+
```

I'm looking for a `SELECT` query that gives me the `MIN` time greater or equal to the date where a **Reset** is logged in the `context` column. If no **Reset** marker exists in the `context` column, I'd like to have the result included.

So for the table above, I expect the result:

```
+--------+-----------------+
| userID |      time       |
+--------+-----------------+
|    111 | 7/15/2019       |
|    222 | 7/8/2020        |
|    333 | 5/11/2020       |
|    444 | 9/8/2020        |
+--------+-----------------+
```

I tried :

```
SELECT * FROM foo as a 
WHERE ((SELECT MIN(a.time) FROM foo) >= (SELECT Max(a.time) FROM foo where context = 'Reset')) group by userID
```

does not produce my expected output, but returns:

```
+--------+-----------+
| userID |   time    |
+--------+-----------+
|    111 | 7/1/2021  |  <--- wrong 
|    222 | 7/8/2020  |
|    333 | 5/11/2020 |
+--------+-----------+
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: I'm using MySQL with PhpMyAdmin and gping to edit my question with this information

Comment: The specified expected result is the "_equal to the date where a Reset_" rows. Doesn't "_bigger or_" add any rows?

Comment: Do you want one row per userid?

Comment: yes, I am looking for a result with one row per UserID,

Comment: Add the row (444,'9/8/2020') to the sample data, and adjust the specified result if needed.

Comment: thanks for the input... I would like that row as well in the output

Comment: Store dates using a date data type, and see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basis on your expected result, You may try below query -

```
SELECT userID, MAX(time)
  FROM YOUR_TABLE
 WHERE context = 'RESET'
 GROUP BY userID
 UNION ALL
SELECT userID, MAX(time)
  FROM YOUR_TABLE
 WHERE context IS NULL
 GROUP BY userID
 ORDER BY userID
```

Answer (score 2):

Use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       coalesce(next_time, time) as imputed_time
from (select t.*,
             sum(context = 'reset') over (partition by user_id) as cnt_reset,
             min(case when context is null then time end) over (partition by userid order by time rows between current row and unbounded following) as next_time
      from t
     ) t
where cnt_reset = 0 or context = 'reset';
```