# Adjust MIN(date) based on other rows value

Tags: mysql, sql

Table:

```
+----+--------+------------+------+---------+-----------------+
| id | userID | difference | type | context |      time       |
+----+--------+------------+------+---------+-----------------+
| 83 |    111 |         30 |      |         | 7/15/2019 15:23 |
| 84 |    111 |         10 |      |         | 7/16/2019 15:28 |
| 85 |    111 |        -10 |      | Reset   | 7/16/2020 15:28 |
| 86 |    222 |         50 |      |         | 7/8/2020 15:28  |
| 87 |    222 |        -10 |      | Reset   | 7/8/2020 15:28  |
| 88 |    333 |        -10 |      | Reset   | 5/11/2020 13:15 |
| 89 |    333 |         10 |      |         | 7/16/2019 13:16 |
| 91 |    111 |         20 |      |         | 7/17/2019 23:15 |
+----+--------+------------+------+---------+-----------------+
```

I'm looking for a query that gives back the SUM of "difference"(>0) for every userID that has a MIN date of '16/7/2019'  with the exeption, that if this userID has a Reset in the context row a MIN Date smaller than that where the Reset is logged has to be ignored.

So the Output should look like:

```
+--------+-------------+
| userID | SUM(points) |
+--------+-------------+
|    111 |          30|
+--------+-------------+
```

My try:

```
SELECT userID, SUM(case when difference > 0 then difference else 0 end),    
FROM test WHERE (CASE 
WHEN (Select MAX(CAST(time as DATE)) where context ='Reset') > (Select 
MIN(CAST(time as DATE))) THEN (Select MAX(CAST(time as DATE)) where 
context ='Reset') ELSE (Select MIN(CAST(time as DATE))) END) = '7/16/2019' group by userID
```

heres the create for the tabel:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `userID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `difference` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `context` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `time` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `userID`, `difference`, `type`, `context`, `time`)    VALUES
(83, 111, 30, '', '', '2019-07-15 15:23:22'),
(84, 111, 10, '', '', '2019-07-16 15:28:27'),
(85, 111, -10, '', 'Reset', '2020-07-16 15:28:27'),
(86, 222, 50, '', '', '2020-07-08 15:28:27'),
(87, 222, -10, '', 'Reset', '2020-07-08 15:28:27'),
(88, 333, -10, '', 'Reset', '2020-05-11 13:15:05'),
(89, 333, -10, '', '', '2019-07-16 13:16:35'),
(91, 111, 20, '', '', '2019-07-17 23:15:57');
```

Comment: As mentioned previously, in comments to an almost identical question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62817481/get-variable-min-date-based-on-marker-in-row), please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: *I'm using Mysql.* If so use MySQL's date format in sample data and question text. But the best way is to replace sample data in table form with CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts.

Comment: Is your sample data representative of your data - it implies that once reset userid can never acquire more points..

Comment: I updated table, added the query I tried and a Create Statement for the table

Comment: I have read this a few times and still have no idea how you get from your sample data to desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this. For each user find the Reset date and filter by out older records

```
SELECT 
    t1.userId, SUM(points)
FROM 
    table1 t1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT t2.userId, max(t2.date) date
    FROM table2 t2 
    WHERE context = "Reset"
    GROUP BY t2.userId
) resetDates on resetDates.userId = t1.userId
WHERE 
    t1.date >= IFNULL(resetDates.date, "01-01-2020")
GROUP BY 
    t1.userId;
```

Comment: I suspect a userid can have many resets and OP does not want to hardcode them

Comment: this i correct a userID can have multiple resets and the min date should adjust. My question seems to be pretty bad so I'm going to edit it.

Comment: What's wrong with multiple resets? You just need the date of the lates reset for each user. This is done in query for `resetDates` with use of `MAX` function. If no reset was done then default value would be used. This is done by `WHERE` condition with `IFNULL`.